# Node Event Emitter Example

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, observer-pattern

I have, what I think, to be a fairly trivial example of doing what I think might be the Observer pattern while using Node's EventEmitter. That said, I'm still getting my sea legs with Node. When I reviewed this with another developer - it appears right but seems slightly weird.

The weird part is how the LightBulb object is listening to the LightSwitch object. AFAIK, the code works but I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

```
/*jslint node: true */

'use strict';

var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var LightSwitch = function(state) {
    var self = this;
    self.state = typeof state !== 'undefined' ? state : 'off';
};

util.inherits(LightSwitch, events.EventEmitter);

LightSwitch.prototype.changeState = function() {
    var self = this;
    // FIXME use if else
    if (self.state == 'on') {
        self.state = 'off';
        self.emit('off');
    } else if (self.state == 'off') {
        self.state = 'on';
        self.emit('on');
    }
};

var LightBulb = function(LightSwitch) {
    var self = this;
    self.state = 'off';
    self.switch = LightSwitch;

    self.switch.on('on', function() {
        self.state = 'on';
    });

    self.switch.on('off', function() {
        self.state = 'off';
    });
};

LightBulb.prototype.currentState = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('The switch is ' + self.switch.state);
    console.log('The light bulb is ' + self.state);
    console.log('\n');
}

var hallwayLightSwitch = new LightSwitch();

var hallwayLightBulb = new LightBulb(hallwayLightSwitch);

// Default!
console.log('--------- EVERYTHING IS OFF --------------');
console.log('Switch is ' + hallwayLightBulb.switch.state);
console.log('Bulb is ' + hallwayLightBulb.state);
console.log('\n');

// Flick it!
console.log('------------ LIGHTS ON! ------------------');
hallwayLightSwitch.changeState();
hallwayLightBulb.currentState();

// Flick it - again!
console.log('------------ LIGHTS OFF! -----------------');
hallwayLightSwitch.changeState();
hallwayLightBulb.currentState();

// And, flick it - again!
console.log('------------ LIGHTS ON! -----------------');
hallwayLightSwitch.changeState();
hallwayLightBulb.currentState();
```

The console output is then ... as I expect:

```
[terryp@jinx] playing_with_events (master) :: node 02_lightswitch.js
--------- EVERYTHING IS OFF --------------
Switch is off
Bulb is off


------------ LIGHTS ON! ------------------
The switch is on
The light bulb is on


------------ LIGHTS OFF! -----------------
The switch is off
The light bulb is off


------------ LIGHTS ON! -----------------
The switch is on
The light bulb is on
```

Comment: That makes sense to me... the "event" of the switch being thrown is what triggers the bulb turning on or off; that's exactly how it works in real life.

Comment: you're going to need to be careful here with the lack of "new" before your lightswitch reference in the lightbulb constructor. try modifying your test script create several lightbulb objects, then try turning one of them off and watch what happens to the others.